# Execute curl command in nodejs

Tags: node.js, bash, express, curl

`curl -i --upload-file ~/Downloads/tree-736885__480.jpg -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' "uploadURL"`

I have above curl command i need to execute this in nodejs. how can i trigger this ?

i tried to change it to axios but its not working.

```
const uploadMedia = async(media, token) =>{
  console.log(media);
  try {
    if(typeof media.uploadUrl !== undefined) {
      let url = media.uploadUrl;
      try {   
        const { data } = await axios.put(url,media.url, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }      
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

so can i run curl command directly in nodejs ?

Comment: You could use a child process to spawn a curl process. But this is 100% possible in plain JS. If you're using node version >=17 you have `fetch` built in.

Comment: @EliRichardson Where is in node >=17 fetch built in?!

Comment: @Marc I believe with node 17 you have to use a flag to enable it. But node 18 and 19 it just shows a warning when used.

Answer (score 0):

```
var curlCommand = "curl -i --upload-file "+media.url+" -H 'Authorization: Bearer "+token+"' '"+url+"'";
    child.exec(curlCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return false;
      }
      if (stderr) {
        console.log(stderr);
        return true;
      }
  });
```

i used child process for executing curl command in nodejs.

Comment: Also, I have just checked it and saw [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl). Maybe there will be a few developers who want to use it.